# In CakePHP is it possible to set the options you pass to the Form helper create method globally? 

Tags: php, cakephp

In CakePHP is it possible to set the options you pass to the Form helper create method globally?

Since I want a specific form layout to be used on all my forms I am currently having to do this when I create every form.

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
    'class' => 'form-horizontal', 
    'inputDefaults' => array(
        'format' => array('before', 'label', 'between', 'input', 'error', 'after'), 
        'between' => '<div class="controls">', 
        'after' => '</div>', 
        'div' => 'control-group', 
        'error' => array(
            'attributes' => array('wrap' => 'span', 'class' => 'help-inline')
            )
        )
    ));
?>
```

I was wondering if there was a way to specifiy this globally so I didn't need do it with every create call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of starlocke is ok but I would not even want to write these three lines all over the place. :) Neither I think this is really "config data". So here is what I would do:

```
MyFormHelper extends FormHelper {
    public function create($model, $options) {
        $defaults = array(/* YOUR DEFAULT OPTIONS*/);
        $options = Set::merge($defaults, $options);
        //...
    }
}
```

Then simply call it:

$this->MyForm->create('Profile');

or call it with a single option in the 2nd param you want to change somewhere.

Comment: This is what i was looking for. The application i am developing will also most certainly need to extend the For helper as i want to to modify the forms quite a bit.

Since the latest version of CakePHP supports helper aliases there would be no need to use MyForm every where.

Answer (score 6):

Make a configuration somewhere (ie: `app/config/core.php` -- or a similarly included file if you've expanded your configuration system)

```
// [...the rest of the config is above...]
Configure::write('MyGlobalFormOptions', array(
'class' => 'form-horizontal', 
'inputDefaults' => array(
    'format' => array('before', 'label', 'between', 'input', 'error', 'after'), 
    'between' => '<div class="controls">', 
    'after' => '</div>', 
    'div' => 'control-group', 
    'error' => array(
        'attributes' => array('wrap' => 'span', 'class' => 'help-inline')
        )
    )
));
```

Using it looks like this...

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User', Configure::read('MyGlobalFormOptions'));
?>
```

If you need to get more specific for certain special forms...

```
<?php
$more_options = array('class'=>'form-vertical');
$options = array_merge(Configure::read('MyGlobalFormOptions'), $more_options);
echo $this->Form->create('Profile', $options);
?>
```